# How to extend and modify a Wysiwyg form with a accordion functionality

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, wysiwyg

I created a Symfony 6 project and I currently have a form where one of the fields is a wysiwyg field.

Picture here:
[Picture of the wysiwyg field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxwFO.png)

I am now looking to add a additional functionality to this wysiwyg field, and that is a accordion funtionality.

Here is an example of the accordion (scroll to the end on the page):
https://www.zzzcg.me/posredovanje-pri-zaposljavanju-u-inostranstvu/

I looked all over the internet on how to modify the wysiwyg field, but I found nothing helpful. I am starting to believe that this is not possible to make.

Does anyone have any tips for me?

Thank you!

Comment: What is the wysiwyg editor you are using?if tinymce this can help : https://www.tiny.cloud/blog/add-accordion-component/ if surmmernote see this: https://github.com/cocaux/summernote-accordion.